# How to remove the containing "response" tag from GET output

Tags: 8

It seems whenever Drupal 8 generates an XML output it gets wrapped in `<response>` tags. I'm defining a custom rest resource (e.g. [like this](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21dblog%21src%21Plugin%21rest%21resource%21DBLogResource.php/class/DBLogResource/8)) and can see no way of modifying this containing tag. The service which is consuming the XML feed breaks when it encounters this tag. Is there anyway I can remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rest plugins always use the standard seralization methods, you can't really influence that for just your plugin. You could implement your own, like ?_format=my_fancy_xml.

Or, if you have very specific needs an an existing client that you need to work with, you can always just implement a normal controller and build the XML yourself and return it with a normal Response object.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response, perhaps a custom REST format is the way to go. Will take a look at how much work that is.

Comment: Finally managed it using these docs: https://www.drupal.org/node/1900312